# Is there a limit to the number of tables allowed in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a limit to the number of tables I can have in BigQuery?  I'm trying to create multiple small tables to reduce query costs.  Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK The limit is on storage capacity. [Their pricing page](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/pricing)  shows a limit of 2 TB.

Answer (score 6):

There is no limit to the number of tables. You might have problems querying them all since there is a 10k limit to the length of a query string.

Comment: Where is that 10k limit documented? As far as I know, the limit is closer to 8MB.

Comment: Quote:
   "Maximum query length: 10KB"

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/quota-policy#queries

Comment: Vukasin: Thanks for pointing that out. The docs are in error. You can do much larger queries than 10KB.

Answer (score 6):

Now it's:

```
Maximum number of tables referenced per query — 1,000
Maximum unresolved legacy SQL query length — 256 KB
Maximum unresolved standard SQL query length — 1 MB
Maximum resolved legacy and standard SQL query length — 12 MB
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas

Answer (score 4):

There is no limit in number of tables you can create. If you have more than a few thousand tables, listing a dataset may be slow (and opening the UI might be slow), but otherwise you can create as many tables as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#table_limits).
There is no maximum number of standard tables.
but partitioned table have limit. (4,000)
and if there are so many tables, api can be slow and have limitation to see table on console.
When you use an API call, enumeration performance slows as you approach 50,000 tables in a dataset. The Cloud Console can display up to 50,000 tables for each dataset.